# Connecting to Snowflake using SSO from JupyterHub running on AWS EC2

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting on behalf of a Snowflake client)

.........................

I have set up JupyterHub running on an Ubuntu EC2 instance. We have also started using SSO in Snowflake.

However, whenever I try to actually use the snowflake connection I get the following error:

```
DatabaseError: 250009 (08001): Failed to connect to DB: <REDACTED>.eu
west-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443, Unable to open a browser in this environment.
```

Seems like there was a similar challenge here:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000095j13y/unable-to-connect-snowflakes-using-jupyter-notebook-running-on-ubuntu-server

...but there didn't seem to be a clear answer in that thread.

I realise this is almost definitely a problem with the EC2 instance rather than with Snowflake but I wouldnt know where to begin fixing this.

.........................

Any recommendations?  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on a console? The error message indicates that there is no web browser available. The SSO is browser-based and thus needs to be able to open a web browser.

Native SSO (meaning no browser needed) is available only through Okta at this time.

Reference: 
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#browser-based-sso